# Is $ \{A\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}: 0<\det(A)<2\} $ compact?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

I have the set $ K:=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}: 0<\det(A)<2\} $ in $ (\mathbb{R}^{n,n},\|.\|_F) $.

I don't know how to show if this set is compact or not compact in $ (\mathbb{R}^{n,n},\|.\|_F) $.

My first idea was to show that this set is compact by contradiction.

Assume there exists an open cover $ (U_i)_{i\in I} $ which contains $ K $ such that for all finite open covers $ (U_i)_{i\in E} $ with $ E\subseteq I $ finite don't contain $ K $ which means $ K\nsubseteq \bigcup\limits_{i\in E} U_i$.

Comment: Hint: start with the special case of $n = 1$.

Comment: So then I have the open interval $ ]0,2[ $ which is compact.

Comment: Second hint: If $K$ were compact, what can you say about the image of $det(A)$ considering that $det(\cdot)$ is a continuous map?

Comment: $K$ is an open set, hence it is not compact.

Comment: I suggest that you revise a bit the introductory theory about compact sets if you consider $(0,2)$ as a compact.

Answer (score 8):

The set is not even bounded as the diagonal matrices
$$
\pmatrix{ k \\ & \frac1k \\ && 1\\ &&&\ddots\\ &&&&1}
$$
belong to the set for all $k$. That is, changing the restriction to $\det (A)=1$ would not affect non-compactness.

Answer (score 3):

$K$ is not compact. To see this, note that $\det : \mathbb{R}^{n,n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous map. Thus, $$K = \mathrm{det}^{-1} (0,2)$$
is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. Since $\mathbb{R}^{n,n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is connected, it follows that $K$ is not compact.

Comment: How do you conclude that being open implies not being compact? You should at least mention to the OP that the space of matrices is connected being it homeomorphic to an euclidean space.

Comment: Indeed; edited to reflect this. @SonGohan

Comment: It suffices to say that $K$ is not closed which is obvious since the zero-matrix is not in $K$, but  in its closure.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=1$ then $K=\{ A \in \mathbb{R}^1 | 0<\det(A)<2\}$. Hence $K=(0,2)$ which is non compact set.